# Create one sum column based on two conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, sum

I have a dataset df

```
> df
         date group    x
    1  197302     A 0.53
    2  197303     A 0.60
    3  197304     A 0.57
    4  197302     B 0.68
    5  197303     B 0.71
    6  197304     B 0.65
    7  197302     C 0.16
    8  197303     C 0.25
    9  197304     C 0.22
    10 197302     D 0.31
    11 197303     D 0.39
    12 197304     D 0.36
```

I want to create a new column 'x.total' where some of the x-values are summed based on two conditions:

1. I only want to sum group A and B with each other and on the other hand and also I only want to sum group C and D with each other.
2. I only want to sum x for dates that are the same. This means that x shouldn't be summed if the date is 197302 for group A and 197303 for group B.

By following these conditions, the results should end up looking like this:

```
     date group    x x.total
1  197302     A 0.53    1.21
2  197303     A 0.60    1.31
3  197304     A 0.57    1.22
4  197302     B 0.68    1.21
5  197303     B 0.71    1.31
6  197304     B 0.65    1.22
7  197302     C 0.16    0.47
8  197303     C 0.25    0.64
9  197304     C 0.22    0.58
10 197302     D 0.31    0.47
11 197303     D 0.39    0.64
12 197304     D 0.36    0.58
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try a tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
read.table(text = "date group    x
    1  197302     A 0.53
    2  197303     A 0.60
    3  197304     A 0.57
    4  197302     B 0.68
    5  197303     B 0.71
    6  197304     B 0.65
    7  197302     C 0.16
    8  197303     C 0.25
    9  197304     C 0.22
    10 197302     D 0.31
    11 197303     D 0.39
    12 197304     D 0.36") %>% 
  mutate(gr = fct_collapse(group, AB = c("A", "B"), CD = c("C", "D"))) %>% 
  group_by(date, gr) %>% 
  mutate(total  = sum(x))
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   date, gr [6]
     date group     x gr    total
    <int> <chr> <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
 1 197302 A     0.53  AB    1.21 
 2 197303 A     0.6   AB    1.31 
 3 197304 A     0.570 AB    1.22 
 4 197302 B     0.68  AB    1.21 
 5 197303 B     0.71  AB    1.31 
 6 197304 B     0.65  AB    1.22 
 7 197302 C     0.16  CD    0.47 
 8 197303 C     0.25  CD    0.64 
 9 197304 C     0.22  CD    0.580
10 197302 D     0.31  CD    0.47 
11 197303 D     0.39  CD    0.64 
12 197304 D     0.36  CD    0.580
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, by using tidyverse and doing a bit of a refactoring of the groups

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~date, ~group, ~num,
  197302L,    "A", 0.53,
  197303L,    "A",  0.6,
  197304L,    "A", 0.57,
  197302L,    "B", 0.68,
  197303L,    "B", 0.71,
  197304L,    "B", 0.65,
  197302L,    "C", 0.16,
  197303L,    "C", 0.25,
  197304L,    "C", 0.22,
  197302L,    "D", 0.31,
  197303L,    "D", 0.39,
  197304L,    "D", 0.36
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(group_2 = ifelse(group %in% c("A","B"),"AB",
                          ifelse(group %in% c("C","D"),"CD","other"))) %>% 
  group_by(date,group_2) %>% 
  mutate(sum = sum(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also do

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(text = "date group    x
    1  197302     A 0.53
    2  197303     A 0.60
    3  197304     A 0.57
    4  197302     B 0.68
    5  197303     B 0.71
    6  197304     B 0.65
    7  197302     C 0.16
    8  197303     C 0.25
    9  197304     C 0.22
    10 197302     D 0.31
    11 197303     D 0.39
    12 197304     D 0.36")

df %>% group_by(date, group %in% c("A", "B")) %>%
  mutate(Total = sum(x))

# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   date, group %in% c("A", "B") [6]
     date group     x `group %in% c("A", "B")` Total
    <int> <chr> <dbl> <lgl>                    <dbl>
 1 197302 A     0.53  TRUE                     1.21 
 2 197303 A     0.6   TRUE                     1.31 
 3 197304 A     0.570 TRUE                     1.22 
 4 197302 B     0.68  TRUE                     1.21 
 5 197303 B     0.71  TRUE                     1.31 
 6 197304 B     0.65  TRUE                     1.22 
 7 197302 C     0.16  FALSE                    0.47 
 8 197303 C     0.25  FALSE                    0.64 
 9 197304 C     0.22  FALSE                    0.580
10 197302 D     0.31  FALSE                    0.47 
11 197303 D     0.39  FALSE                    0.64 
12 197304 D     0.36  FALSE                    0.580
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("
 date   group    x
 197302     A 0.53
 197303     A 0.60
 197304     A 0.57
 197302     B 0.68
 197303     B 0.71
 197304     B 0.65
 197302     C 0.16
 197303     C 0.25
 197304     C 0.22
 197302     D 0.31
 197303     D 0.39
 197304     D 0.36"
)
group1 <- c("A","B")
group2 <- c("C","D")

df[, x.sum := fcase(
  group %chin% group1, sum(.SD[group %chin% group1,x]),
  group %chin% group2, sum(.SD[group %chin% group2,x])
  ),
  by=date][]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum` in `ave` for the groups `date` and `group %in% c("A", "B")`:

```
df$x.total <- ave(df$x, df$date, df$group %in% c("A", "B"), FUN=sum)
df
#     date group    x x.total
#1  197302     A 0.53    1.21
#2  197303     A 0.60    1.31
#3  197304     A 0.57    1.22
#4  197302     B 0.68    1.21
#5  197303     B 0.71    1.31
#6  197304     B 0.65    1.22
#7  197302     C 0.16    0.47
#8  197303     C 0.25    0.64
#9  197304     C 0.22    0.58
#10 197302     D 0.31    0.47
#11 197303     D 0.39    0.64
#12 197304     D 0.36    0.58
```